# database design - ERD Modeling question for Graph within AWS

Tags: graph, nosql, data-modeling

I have an ERD for a DB design for an RDBMS. 
Dataset has many to many relationship with Policy based on the Dataset's type attribute. The Dataset Entity has many attributes.

The problem is the Dataset can have additional attributes in the future to query by. Now, that leads to me a NOSQL DB like DynamoDB. But the unknown queries by the additional attributes leads me(IMHO) towards a Graph model on top of a NoSQL DB. 
So, I can then have the following Graph relationship:

Dataset has a Type. Type has a Policy. Type also has a default policy if none is provided. This is to model the many to many relationship of Dataset with Policy for the Dataset type. I can attend additional attributes to the Dataset entity later on and have it get added to the NOSQL DB and also query it using a Graph model(Neptune) on top of the NOSQL ? Is this the right way to model this ?

[image]

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a different solution to the problem of handling additional future attributes using Postgres with a jsonb column for Dataset entity.

```
metadata jsonb,
```

So, you can add as many new attributes within this json and push it to the jsonb column.
I can then query it like this in the WHERE clause:

```
metadata->>'startIdx' <= '${startIdx}'
```

The Table will not need to change with a new field but the query will need to accommodate the new field in the query. A long time ago, xml was used instead of json for this same concept but the RDBMS didn't have a way to query inside the json data in the column.

[Postgres Jsonb Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)